# Is it problematic to run python script constantly in the background?

Tags: python

I've wrote a simple code to send my mother a message every x seconds.

I would like to know :

1. Can I just run my code in the background 24/7 in the background without issues?
2. Is there another way ?

This is my code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import time

account_sid = 'private'
auth_token = 'private'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

starttime=time.time()
while True:
    message = client.messages.create(
    from_='+xxxxx',
    body="message text",
    to = '+xxxxxxxx')
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
    print(message.sid)
```

Comment: cron / cron jobs are specifically designed to tackle this issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two options.

1. Use Nohup to run your script in the background. Like use the following command:

   `nohup python -u your_script.py &`

   It will create a `nohup.out` file, and you can `vim` it to check the status.
2. Use Crontab to run your script every x minutes.
   In your example, if you want to run your script every minute, you can set crontab as: `* * * * * python your_script.py`. Please note that crontab cannot support the period less than 1 minute. To do this, you can write a bash file and run it. And you can delete the `time.sleep` line inside your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  python your_script.py
  sleep x
done
```

Comment: I tried everything about crontab and its not working. I tried your example, I tried using cd Desktop and gave the python3 path and my_scrypt.py, all on the same line, nothing worked!

Comment: It may caused by the environment variables. Two options. First, login in as root,  and for the python script, try to input the full path of your python file, like `python /from/your/own/path/your_script.py`. Second, if you cannot login in as root, add variable path at the top of the crontab. For example, `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`. Then try crontab again.@CodingN00b